# setting new column labeled with range in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, keyerror

from tensorflow import keras

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/Salary_Data.csv',header=None)

=============================================

I want to make a new column of dataframe called highincome which has value 0 when the value of 'Salary' column is lower than 100000, and value 1 when the value of 'Salary' column is 100000, or higher than 100000.

I am really poor at coding.. so I alreay had help from Google Bard then it answered below:

df['highincome'] = (df['Salary'] >= 100000) | (df['Salary'] > 100000)

but!! colab showed

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Salary'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
3805             except TypeError:
3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'Salary'

=========

.. really don't have idea what keyerror salary truly means

Salary_Data.csv is here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mohithsairamreddy/salary-data

Comment: Remove `header=None` and use `df = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')`. And regarding the high income, use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) this way : `df['highincome'] = (~df['Salary'].between(0, 100000, inclusive="left")).astype(int)`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked successfully! I really appreciate your help.